# Laravel validation not required but still comes back as if it is required

Tags: laravel, validation

Having some slight issues with laravel validation rules. I.e. I have setup a form with a field name of 'url'. This url needs to be a URL but is not required.

So I have:

```
'url' => 'url',
```

In the validation rules, but it still comes back on submit that the URL is an invalid format. But I didn't fill it out and it isn't required.

Slightly confused here, anything I should look out for here?

Comment: Try `'url' => ['nullable', 'url']`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, that seems to of done it, I've written validation rules before and never had to use this. Strange but thanks!

Comment: I believe the middleware are newer additions. I too got tripped up by it recently. Glad I could help, I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

> By default, Laravel includes the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the  `App\Http\Kernel class`. Because of this, you will often need to mark your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid.

So, this validation rule will do the trick:

```
'url' => ['nullable', 'url']
```

Comment: I can't accept right now, need to wait 9 minutes. :-)

Answer (score -1):

For that, I usually use `nullable` in the very beginning

```
'url' => 'nullable|url',
```

Comment: Why duplicate my answer?